# Storing large data sets for python machine learning algorithm consumption

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata

I'm reading up on how to clean/munge/wrangle data sets in order to run machine learning algorithms on them. Lots of info on how to do the actual wrangling, but a practical detail seems to be glossed over: storage.

My question is quite simple: **which is the go-to technology to store/retrieve a large data set** in order to run algorithms on it in the most convenient/efficient way possible?

I'm guessing the language in which the algorithms are written is not all that relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of technologies out there to handle. These are the most popular ones I know of:

For moderate data to operate in chunks- Pandas -  pd.read_csv('train.csv', chunksize=chunksize)

For larger data - dask, Hadoop with R

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055502/recommended-package-for-very-large-dataset-processing-and-machine-learning-in-r) for various other suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Currently `Apache Hadoop` is one of the popular technologies to store data and `Apache Spark` is a very popular computational engine to compute/munge large datasets.